# .htaccess RewriteRules matched, but rewritten wrongly

Tags: apache

On my server I have a .htaccess file with the following contents:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myhost.local$
RewriteRule ^default/.*$ /index.php?id=12345 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myhost.local$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myhost.local/default/home [R=302,NC]
```

The phenomenon is that when requesting http://myhost.local/, instead of being 302 redirected to http://myhost.local/default/home as expected, I am being 301 (!) redirected back to http://myhost.local/, resulting in an infinite loop.

Another strange thing is that `^/$` never seems to match my URL even though it should, so I have to use `^/?` with a question mark for some reason. Whenever there's no match, no rewriting happens and therefore there are no infinite loops, so this is further evidence that my `RewriteRule` for `^(.*)$` is indeed picked up on if the Condition is satisfied, only what I want to redirect to and with what code is completely ignored.

For the record, I have also had the rules in this format:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myhost.local$
RewriteRule ^default/.*$ /index.php?id=12345 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myhost.local$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://myhost.local/default/home [R=302,NC]
```

Which resulted in exactly the same thing as the first example.

What is causing the redirection to happen, but not to the URL I actually gave?

Things to note:

- There are other entries in this .htaccess file
- This .htaccess file is within DOCUMENT_ROOT
- The default VirtualHost has `RewriteOptions inherit` set

Comment: You sure you have no more htaccess files or other rules anywhere else?

Comment: No I wasn't. There were. In fact I removed all the other rules and it worked so the problem is among them. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was within the same .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.+/.* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

Which easily explained the 301 as well.